# How to get custom attribute assigned by metadata?

Tags: c#, attributes, metadata

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestAttributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class TestAttribute : Attribute { }

    public class TestClassMetadata
    {
        [Test]
        public object Poperty { get; set; }
    }

    [MetadataType(typeof(TestClassMetadata))]
    public partial class TestClass
    {
        public string Poperty { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestClass test = new TestClass();
            TestAttribute attr = test.GetType().GetProperty("Poperty").GetCustomAttribute<TestAttribute>();
        }
    }
}
```

I have null reference in my attr value. But if I assign the attribute TestAttribute by TestClass definition directly everything will work.

How to get custom attribute assigned by metadata?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clarify what your goal is because `TestClass` "Poperty" doesn't have a `TestAttribute` so you won't be able to find it.  It is on `TestClassMetadata` "Poperty" though so this works just fine.

```
TestClassMetadata test = new TestClassMetadata();
TestAttribute attr = test.GetType().GetProperty("Poperty").GetCustomAttribute<TestAttribute>();
```